# cross compile: error adding symbols: File in wrong format

Tags: android, cross-compiling, arm64

I'm trying to cross compile fdk-aac for arm-v8.

here is my build script:

```
#!/bin/sh

NDK_HOME=/home/ubuntu/android-ndk-r12b

INSTALL_DIR=/home/ubuntu/compiled
SYSROOT=$NDK_HOME/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK_HOME/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64
CROSS_PREFIX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/aarch64-linux-android-

CC={$CROSS_PREFIX}gcc
CXX={$CROSS_PREFIX}g++
CPP={$CROSS_PREFIX}cpp
CXXCPP={$CROSS_PREFIX}cpp

./configure \
--prefix=$INSTALL_DIR \
--with-sysroot=$SYSROOT \
--host=aarch64 \
--enable-shared \
--with-pic=no \
CC="${CROSS_PREFIX}gcc --sysroot=$SYSROOT" \
CXX="${CROSS_PREFIX}g++ --sysroot=$SYSROOT" \
RANLIB="${CROSS_PREFIX}ranlib" \
AR="${CROSS_PREFIX}ar" \
STRIP="${CROSS_PREFIX}strip" \
NM="${CROSS_PREFIX}nm" \
LD="${CROSS_PREFIX}ld --sysroot=$SYSROOT" \
CFLAGS="-O2 $OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS --sysroot=$SYSROOT" \
CXXFLAGS="-O2 $OPTIMIZE_CFLAGS --sysroot=$SYSROOT"

#make
#make install
```

`make` and `make install` are useless, because `./configure` failed and the error message ask me to check the `config.log`:

```
configure:3243: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:3265: /home/ubuntu/android-ndk-r12b/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/aarch64-linux-android-gcc --sysroot=/home/ubuntu/android-ndk-r12b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/ -O2  --sysroot=/home/ubuntu/android-ndk-r12b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/   conftest.c >&5
/home/ubuntu/android-ndk-r12b/platforms/android-16/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:3269: $? = 1
configure:3307: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "fdk-aac"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "fdk-aac"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "0.1.4"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "fdk-aac 0.1.4"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencore-amr/"
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define PACKAGE "fdk-aac"
| #define VERSION "0.1.4"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:3312: error: in `/home/ubuntu/fdk-aac-0.1.4':
configure:3314: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

I don't know which config is wrong about the build script. This is my first time to cross compile library for ARM64...

Comment: Is "arch-arm" definitely a 64-bit sysroot, not a 32-bit one?

Comment: @Notlikethat, arch-arm is a 32-bit platform. I don't see arch-arm64 under android-16 in my copy of the NDK, but that platform does exist for API levels 21+.

Comment: To be sure, you could check the header of that `crtbegin_dynamic.o` with readelf/objdump/etc. - if it's 32-bit ARM code, you'll need a 32-bit ARM toolchain. Note that it's not uncommon these days for 64-bit machines to run a 64-bit kernel but a 32-bit userspace, particularly with Android (where all the 32-bit stuff has to be there anyway for compatibility, and having to have 64-bit versions alongside eats an awful lot of space).

Answer (score 1):

I have add these two statements "SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "mips-linux-uclibc-gnu-gcc") 
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER  "mips-linux-uclibc-gnu-g++") " and build success, maybe help you.